# JS set input value by regex

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, input

I have simple input on my html and i want to when user putting text value in the input value was automatically set by my regex pattern
Example: I have time picker input[image]
and I want the user when he enters numbers, the value is automatically formatted in the input.
How to do it with regex and replace function ?

I tried to do it this way, but in the end I just get the string that I enter.

```
console.log(value.replace(/^(([0-9]{1})|([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1})|([2]{1}[0-3]{1}))(([:]{1})?)(([0-5]{1}[0-9]?)?)$/g, ''));
```

Comment: This is not a good example for using regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UI framework, refer to their documentation they would probably have a plugin to do it for you. Or if you want to do it on your own:

From the HTML side you can use [`type="time"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) attribute (please check the [browser support for this](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_input_type_time)).

And from JavaScript you can use something like [`^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$`](https://regexr.com/778jt) on form submission for example.

```js
const TIME_REGEX = /([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$/;

const myTimeElm = document.getElementById('myTime');
const outputElm = document.getElementById('output');

let timer;

outputElm.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (TIME_REGEX.test(myTimeElm.value)) {
    outputElm.innerText = myTimeElm.value;
  } else {
    outputElm.innerText = "Error!"
  }
});
```

```css
#output {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="myTime" value="00:00">

<span id="output">click here!</span>
```

If you don't want to use HTML's type="time", consider using a mask for your input where you record the user's input and render the formatted output in a different component.

Since using the RegEx alone won't achieve the same user experience as you may want to workout the input's cursor position.

Or simple use a library that does that for you ([Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) for example)

Comment: You suggestion about cleave.js very useful

Comment: Nice! I hope it answered your question